# Optimize JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have a database of students with a number of tardy instances in a Google Sheet. When they hit 5, 8, or 11 tardies, they have a disciplinary action logged. The disciplinary actions are noted in the following three columns for 5, 8, and 11 tardies:

`| Stu name    | # tardies | 5 cons  | 8 cons   | 11 cons|
|-------------|-----------|---------|----------|--------|
| Joe Doe     | 5         | 1/2 ISS |          |        |
| Mark Dark   | 5         |         |          |        |
| Steve Leave | 8         | 1/2 ISS | Full ISS |        |`

The loop takes a target number of tardies and compares the # tardies column. A `stu` array is returned if the consequence column for the number of tardies is *blank*.

Right now, the loop runs, but it's really clunky. Is there something I could do to optimize the way the nested `if` statements run?

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var stu = [data[i][0], data[i][1]];
    if(target === 5) {
      if(data[i][3] === 5 && data[i][4] == 0) {
        array.push(stu);
      }
    } else if(target === 8) {
      if(data[i][3] === 8 && data[i][5] == 0) {
        array.push(stu);
      }
    } else if(target === 12) {
      if(data[i][3] === 12 && data[i][6] == 0) {
        array.push(stu);
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what kind of optimization do you expect and why the question includes the google-apps-script tag as the code doesn't include any class or method of Google Apps Script. Do you want less lines of code? Do you want to improve performance? Related: 1) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286557/is-it-okay-to-ask-code-optimization-help, 2) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @Rubén In my reading about JavaScript loops, it seemed like using nested loops was a bad idea because it can lead to slow performance, poor readability, etc. It's working code, I'm just wondering if there are things I should be doing to write _better_ code.

Answer (score 0):

Just move out your conditions so it's just 3 conditions?
  Like so:

```
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        var stu = [data[i][0], data[i][1]];
        if(target === 5 && data[i][3] === 5 && data[i][4] == 0) {
            array.push(stu);
        } else if(target === 8 && data[i][3] === 8 && data[i][5] == 0) {
            array.push(stu);
        } else if(target === 12 && data[i][3] === 12 && data[i][6] == 0) {
            array.push(stu);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

in fact since target is not modified inside the for loop you can even move it out:

```
var onTarget = {
    5: function(data, array){
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            if(data[i][3] === 5 && data[i][4] == 0){
                array.push(stu)
            }
        }
    },
    8: function(data, array){
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
            if(data[i][3] === 8 && data[i][5] == 0){
                array.push(stu)
            }
        }
    }
}
if(target in onTarget){
    onTarget[target](data, array);
}
```

It is a bit verbose and the code dupplicates so you can play on indices now...

```
var targetToColumnUplet = {
    5: {value:5, blankIndex: 4}
    8: {value:8, blankIndex: 5}
}

if(target in targetToColumnUplet){
    var uplet = targetToColumnUplet[target];
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        var stu = [data[i][0], data[i][1]];
        if(data[i][3] === uplet.value && data[i][uplet.blankIndex] == 0) {
            array.push(stu);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Google Apps Script doesn't support arrow functions.

Comment: replaced arrow functions via raw functions.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this.

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    var stu = [data[i][0], data[i][1]];
    var d3 = data[i][3];
    switch(d3){
        case 5:
           if(data[i][4] === 0){
               array.push(stu);
           } 
           break;
        case 8:
           if(data[i][5] === 0){
               array.push(stu);
           } 
           break;
        case 12:
           if(data[i][6] === 0){
               array.push(stu);
           } 
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear how this is better than the question code. Please explain.